# Unable to get userid using Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: facebook

I am building a Facebook app and need to get the userid directly from Facebook. I intend to use Facebook PHP SDK to get the userid but it always crash my server.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
require 'facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

echo $user;
?>
```

I always get the server error message:

```
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk. Can someone help me with regards to this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found out the error. It turns out that there's an error in the base_facebook.php file. You need to modify the getCurrentUrl() function to redirect to the app URL that you used in the App Settings. Hope that save someone from debugging for hours!

Comment: You should not be changing base_facebook.php. The way you fixed it is a hack since if you had to copy it to another host it would break. The better way to fix it is to figure out why getCurrentUrl is not working and change your HTTP server settings. Most likely your server is not correctly providing something like $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

Comment: Yes, it is not providing the correct $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and I couldn't change the server settings. That's why I need to change the base_facebook.php file.